# Mopidy with mopidy-spotify doesn't play anything

Tags: ubuntu, alsa

I am using Ubuntu 16 and after installing mopidy and mopidy-spotify I came across this error:

```
Mixer (AlsaMixer) initialization error: Could not find ALSA soundcard with index 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that we are playing a sound with a wrong interface/card configuration. First we need to know wich is the correct interface (e.g.):

```
#aplay -l

placa 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Dispositivo secundário: 0/1
Dispositivo secundário #0: subdevice #0
placa 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Dispositivo secundário: 1/1
Dispositivo secundário #0: subdevice #0
```

For my configuration I have one card (card zero , i.e = 0) and two devices: 3 and 7.

Now we have to guess what is the current device we are using, try 0,3 and 0,7:

```
aplay -D plughw:0,3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
aplay -D plughw:0,7 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

The correct configuration is the one who will allow to listen to something (in my case was 0,3)..

Finally, we just need to configure the correct parameters for mopidy on /etc/mopidy/mopidy.conf:

```
[audio]
mixer = alsamixer
output = alsasink device=hw:0,3
```

Now restart the mopidy, and we are ready to go!

```
sudo service mopidy restart
```

More information:

```
http://acquisitionsyndrome.com/2014/09/spotify-using-mopidy/
```